# the stakes go beyond something

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is from [a *Washington Post* article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2022/03/04/russia-ukraine-internet-cogent-cutoff/).

> “You have to be a sophisticated news consumer in order to find
> credible information,” said Alexander Gabuev, a senior fellow at the
> Carnegie Moscow Center, a think tank. “Accessing different from the
> Kremlin’s point of view takes extra effort.”
>
> But **the stakes go beyond** news and information — even at this highly
> charged, sensitive moment.

I wonder what the part in bold means in the above context.

Is it an idiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stakes are whatever is at risk - although the word is used with various shades of meaning in different contexts, and frequently found in betting.

What is at stake is what you stand to gain or lose, whether money, a contract, a job, a promotion, or anything else you are trying to achieve.

So, what the statement is saying is that there is more at risk than just news and information. There is much more than may be lost or gained.

Comment: Thank you very much.